# Referenced bean 'entityManagerFactory' not found

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot 2.1.1 Application that uses hibernate for data access. I'm leveraging spring boot autoconfiguration for all datasource and hibernate configurations. The Application runs properly but I see this `WARNING` in the problem view and i don't like it. I find it strange since i'm not defining ay beans by myself. please help

Comment: Can you add stacktrace logs?

Comment: No stacktrace. This is a compile time issue.